# Why does java compiler generates multiple .class files for single java File?

Tags: java, class, compiler-construction

Why does java compiler generates multiple .class files for single java File ?

I have written some java code Deadlock.java , on compiling this it generated multiple classes 
Named Deadlock$someNumber.class .

Why does this happen .??

What is the Significance of it ??

Comment: Because you have other classes defined in your file like non public classes, inner classes, anonymous classes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I beleive it usually does that when you use anonymous inner classes. Each of those classes will get a class file but as you declared no name for them , it gets a number. So any unnamed class declaration you created (perhaps for Runnable or Listeners etc) is probably creating those.

Comment: An anonymous class would generate `Deadlock$.class` file

Answer (score 3):

If you have several classes in the same file (one of them is necessary public and has the same name as the file), say that in your Person.java file, you have the following

```
    public class Person{
}
class Classroom{
}
```

The compiler will create a class for each class in the file Person.java

Comment: Not necessarily buddy, one class must invoke the other in order to produce the xxxx$xxx.class. The above merely creates 2 separate class files, even if they're defined inside a single file. You'll need to actually define the class inside the other: `public class Person { } class Classroom { Person p = new Person() { private void someMethod() { } };}`

Answer (score 1):

These are anonymous classes. Your code contains something like `new SomeInterface(){}` and/or `new SomeClass(){}`.

Comment: That's not the result of an anonymous class.